# Can I submit the same app to the App Store under multiple, different accounts/identities?

Tags: iphone, app-store

Working for a digital agency, you get a lot of interesting requests! :)

I have a client who has asked a rather strange question:

Is it possible to submit the same app to the App Store under multiple, different accounts/identities?

So if you search for Company A in the App Store, you would get this app as a result, and if you also searched for Company B, you would also get this app as a result.

Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't you be asking the App Store this not SO?

Comment: @Matti - sed/App Store/google/gp for many questions - but the Creator wants this to be THE site for tech knowledge - and it seems to be working.  Note: and they have a point - now if only people would search SO before asking a question :(

Comment: Agreed, this isn't a programming question, but one about App Store policies.  I'd highly recommend asking at Apple's Developer Forums instead: http://devforums.apple.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the AppStore Review Guidelines Apple recently published.

> 2.20 Developers "spamming" the App Store with many versions of similar apps will be removed from the iOS Developer Program

Additionally, I think it'd be wise to advise your client against such a move, as it will only cause fragmentation for the app. Apps have keywords, so perhaps you should focus there to increase search results. I think you'd run into some issues submitting the same app to the store under different developer accounts--not to mention that you have to have individual developer accounts to even attempt such submissions. It'd really be a headache.

Comment: What about in the case of branded Apps? The company I work for wants to submit the same App with identical code, but different resource files (images, URLs, etc). The customers would purchase an add-on to our main product that yields an iOS app that their users can download for free to get instant access to their services.

Answer (score 2):

Technically, yes. At least if you're using different App-IDs and sign it with the distribution certificate for the account you'd like to upload it under.

I do not know however if Apple checks for 100% identical code / apps while reviewing apps - if not, it would propably work, if no, propably not :)

Answer (score 0):

Even if multiple developers could get the same app approved, they would still have to change the app ID and the app name, so the search results would not show the same app, but multiple similar apps, all with different reviews and ratings, the aggregate of which would all be far lower in the popularity rankings.