# Is it possible to submit same app with different name?

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

Has anybody tried to submit the same app with different name to the app store?
Assumed that the app is under the same iOS developer program account, and is not a lite version.

Thanks ^m^

Comment: This might be related; they say "no": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727729/can-i-submit-the-same-app-to-the-app-store-under-multiple-different-accounts-ide

Comment: Why on earth would you do this? This is the kind of stuff that ruins the App Store. I seriously hope you never get an app onto the App Store. So trashy.

Comment: i am also having same requirement. We are developing an app which contain different versions so is it possible to submit different version with different name in app store . no ui changes or colour changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't. You should not try to submit the same app under a different name to the App Store. It is not how the App Store works. As @Jeremiah said, there is a similar thread on StackOverflow: [Can I submit the same app to the App Store under multiple, different accounts/identities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727729/can-i-submit-the-same-app-to-the-app-store-under-multiple-different-accounts-ide) and in it, @bobwaycott notes that the App Store Guidelines state:

> 2.20 Developers "spamming" the App Store with many versions of similar
>   apps will be removed from the iOS
>   Developer Program

Comment: To answer the original question: Yes, in previous years nearly identical duplicate apps have been submitted and approved.  However, Apple appears to no longer be approving them, and has changed the iOS SDK agreement to say submitting such apps is no longer allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all you have to do is to copy your project to a different location, and rename it:

http://aplus.rs/programming/how-to-rename-project-in-xcode-3x/

It will be treated as a different project with configuration rewritten by xcode.

Comment: Technically, yes. But Apple's Guidelines warn against it.

Comment: Thanks everybody ^^ Assuming that I have an app named "MyApp01", and it is already in the AppStore. Now I want to submit another app with the name "HisApp01" but the functionality, content of the app is almost identical with "MyApp01". Would Apple allow this?

Comment: @Rae No! Stop. Get off the App Store. Or tell me what your current app is so that I can report you to Apple!